# Samba not giving correct permissions in Windows

Tags: samba

I have create mask, force create mask, create dir. mask, force create dir. mask, on 0777 but it is not giving any permissions to my Windows computer. Please help lol

Comment: heya! You might have more luck asking Windows questions on Windows OS forums rather than Ubuntu OS. Most of us use Ubuntu instead of Windows.

Best of luck

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was running Samba on a Raspberry Pi 2B and was trying to access the folder with a Windows computer. It's been a year though, I've moved on haha